# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^3} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^3} dx$ I wasnt exactly sure how to approach this. I saw some similar examples that used Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: The function is even since $(-x)^2 = x^2$. Why would you need a branch cut? All you have are the poles at $z = \pm i$ of order three.

Comment: Integrate over a large semi-circle in the upper (or lower) halfplane and use the residue theorem (or Cauchy's integral formula and some algebra).

Comment: Why not just finding an antiderivative? Your integrand is even by the way.

Comment: @dustin, that was one of my initial thoughts too but after looking at some similar examples i threw that out.

Comment: Just use the Residue Theorem for poles of order 3 and you should be good to go barring algebra errors.

Comment: Nevermind didn't noticed tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^3} = 2\pi i\cdot\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^3},z=i\right)=\pi i\left.\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{(z-i)^3}{(z^2+1)^3}\right|_{z=i}=\color{red}{\frac{3\pi}{8}}. $$

Comment: why dont we find the residue for the $-i$ pole as well?

Comment: @cele $x$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, so if we only range $x$ from $-R$ to $R$ and then connect via a circular arc, we have a semi circle in the UHP or LHP. Therefore, only one pole is enclosed in the contour. Of course, we take $\lim_{R\to\infty}$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, I see, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I'm still a little unsure of how you went from step 2 to step 3, the line starting with $\pi i$

Comment: @cele: how do you compute the residue of $f(z)$ in $z=z_0$, knowning that $f(z)$ has a triple pole in $z_0$? You have to take: $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left((z-z_0)^3 f(z)\right)|_{z=z_0}.$$

Comment: Ok, most of the examples I've done involved doing the Taylor series

Comment: @cele: the reason is that, if the Laurent series of $f(z)$ around $z=z_0$ is something like $$f(z)=\frac{\gamma}{(z-z_0)^3}+\frac{\beta}{(z-z_0)^2}+\frac{\alpha}{z-z_0}+\ldots$$ by the previous manipulations you extract the value of $\alpha$, i.e. the residue.

Comment: I cannot get this second derivative, i keep getting something different. Is there a simpler way to calculate it? I have calculated it by hand several times with varying degrees of similar anwswers. Wolfram Alpha states that it is $\frac{12}{(z+i)^5}$, and when evaluated for i, and multiplied by $\pi i$, it does equal $\frac {3\pi}{8}$, I just cant get to that

Comment: @cele: it is not so difficult, you have just to compute $$\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{1}{(z+i)^3}.$$

Comment: ok, i reworked it, but got $\frac{3\pi}{16}$, which is still slightly off

Comment: @cele: $$\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{1}{(z+i)^3}=\frac{12}{(z+i)^5}$$ whose value in $i$ is $-\frac{3i}{8}$. Multiplying by $\pi i$ you get $\frac{3\pi}{8}$.

Comment: ok, i finally saw my mistake. thank you so much for your patience and help

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}^{3}}}
=\left.\totald[2]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + \mu}
\right\vert_{\, \mu\ =\ 1}
=\left.\totald[2]{}{\mu}\pars{\mu^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}
\right\vert_{\, \mu\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm]&={\pi \over 2}\,\left.\totald[2]{\mu^{-1/2}}{\mu}\right\vert_{\, \mu\ =\ 1}
={\pi \over 2}\,\pars{{3 \over 4}\,\mu^{-5/2}}_{\, \mu\ =\ 1}
=\color{#66f}{\large{3\pi \over 8}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Another way is a trig substitution $x = \tan u$ which reduces the integrand to
$$
\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^3}
 = \int \frac{\sec u \tan u}{\sec^6 u} du
 = \int \sin u \cos^4 u du
 = \frac{\cos^5 u}{5}
$$
and the rest is arithmetic

Comment: @dustin did not see the tag

Comment: @gt6989b, i had thought a substitution as well, but did not find it relevent to problems i had worked previously

Comment: That's not right. $dx = \sec^2 u \,du$ so the integral is $\int \cos^4 u \, du$

Answer (score 1):

$x=\tan{u}\rightarrow \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=du$

So the problem reduces to

$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^4{u}\space du$

Comment: @dustin Yes, you are right